# Proof that a reflection in the plane preserves angle measure

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, proof-explanation, isometry

One proof of the SAS criterion for triangle congruece relies on the "rigid motion" (isometry) definition of congruent figures and the properties of rigid motions in the plane. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30dOn3QARVU&feature=youtu.be) for an animated walk through of the argument.

At 1:46, the video states that "basic rigid motions preserve degrees in angles." The proofs that I have seen of this statement assume SAS in the first place.

Is it possible to prove that a rigid motion in the plane maps angles to angles with the same measure, without assuming SAS? If so, is there a source that presents such a proof?

Comment: By "rigid motion," I mean isometry.

In high school geometry, which I'm currently teaching, study of isometries is limited to reflections, rotations, and translations in the plane. I am aware that any isometry in the plane is the composition of at most 3 reflections.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified what one is allowed to use in this proof.

Comment: I am mostly interested in a the proof that does not assume SAS, SSS, or ASA.

Comment: @mathclassfromscratch This is a late comment, but I found your post because I also have the same problem of seeing circular reasoning when I search this area. I found in https://themathpage.com/aBookI/propI-4.htm that Euclide did not really prove SAS and that these days SAS is often considered to be a postulate.